# Display and read all files in directory

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qfile, qdir

I am trying to print out the file names of all files in a directory. However some files do not show up or cannot be opened.

If I restart the program, the files that previously couldn't be opened are in fact opened and displayed.
What is going on?

This is my code:

```
 QDirIterator iterator(dir.absolutePath(), QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
       while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          iterator.next();



              QFile file(iterator.next());

               if ( file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly ) ) {
                     qDebug() << QFileInfo(file).fileName() << endl;


               } else {
                   qDebug() << "Can't open " << QFileInfo(file).fileName() << endl;
               }
       }
```

Comment: What does `file.error()` tell you when you get an error from `open()`?

Comment: I get an output of `5`

Comment: `QFile::OpenError 5 The file could not be opened.` Well I guess that's not terribly helpful. Is there a chance that some other part of your program is opening that file in a non-shared mode?

Comment: Hmm, well I was trying to read in all files from a directory so that I can calculate checksums for them.

Comment: file.error() is bad for error diagnostic. You should use file.errorString(). What does that say?

Comment: I would guess you're skipping files as well because you call `iterator.next()` an extra time without storing the value.

Comment: Why do you advance the iterator twice?! You will skip every second file! Just remove `iterator.next();`.

Comment: *facepalm*
I must be going blind, thanks!

Comment: @RetiredNinja: I think it was not the best idea to remove your answer. It will work, so it is useful. It just lacks some explanation and add further code to it. I just mentioned these, but that does not mean I found it unuseful. I would suggest to undelete it, so that the readers can see also that. Two users already found it useful. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one issue here:

```
 iterator.next();
 QFile file(iterator.next());
 if ( file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly ) ) {
```

You are trying to advance the iterator twice inside the loop. That means that you can potentially loop through the last element which will represent an invalid file which then will fail for obvious reasons.

Depending on the content of the folder, i.e. whether it is changing slightly for the next run, i.e. one file is added or removed, this loop may "work" for the next time, i.e. all the files it tries to open will be opened, but it would have still skipped files in its form.

The proper fix is the remove this line from the iteration:

```
iterator.next();
```

Therefore, your whole code would be this for your convenience:

```
QDirIterator iterator(dir.absolutePath(), QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    QFile file(iterator.next());
    if ( file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly ) )
        qDebug() << "Opened:" << file.fileName() << endl;
    else
        qDebug() << "Can't open " << file.fileName() << file.errorString() << endl;
}
```

At least two things to note as per comments:

- You can use [the errorString() method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qiodevice.html#errorString) for getting more information in such cases.
- You do not need to construct QFileInfo to get the filename. The QFile object [already has a method for that.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfile.html#fileName). The problem is that you are iterating recursively, and as such, you print out only the basenames without knowing where the files reside. You could also display the same file name multiple times if there are files in different subdirectories with the same name.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I used `QFileInfo` because I wanted to display only the file name and not the full path.

Comment: @MicroPenguin: that is not so good an idea. It is always better to provide as much information as possible. In fact, you could potentially display the same names without distinction in different subdirectories!

Comment: Thanks @Laszlo. You seem very knowledgeable with Qt. I'm just beginning to learn how to use the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not use QDir::entryList?

From Qt Assistant:

*QStringList QDir::entryList ( const QStringList & nameFilters, Filters filters = NoFilter, SortFlags sort = NoSort ) const
Returns a list of the names of all the files and directories in the directory, ordered according to the name and attribute filters previously set with setNameFilters() and setFilter(), and sorted according to the flags set with setSorting().*

The name filter, file attribute filter, and sorting specification can be overridden using the nameFilters, filters, and sort arguments.

Returns an empty list if the directory is unreadable, does not exist, or if nothing matches the specification.

See also entryInfoList(), setNameFilters(), setSorting(), and setFilter().

Comment: entryList is not recursive, so you would need to do the recursion yourself. So, the right way is IMHO what the OP is using. You do not seem to point the issue out with that either.